# Detecting the maximum resolution of a html5 video for a given device

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Some mobile devices only support h.264 video decoding at certain resolutions. The iPhone 5 for instance can't decode videos larger than 1080p.

I'm making a site that uses large 360 degree videos as a video texture in webgl but I need to know when the video can't be decoded so i can fallback to a lower resolution.

As far as I can tell, such devices don't emit an error when trying to display the video, they just silently fail.

Is there a way, within a browser to get the maximum video resolution or at least to know if the video has failed to decode.